# Compact subset in the quotient space of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, quotient-spaces

In an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/630314/416552) question, a "long" proof is given. But the question can be equivalently stated, due to open mapping theorem, in the following manner.

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $M\subset X$ a closed subspace. Then, for every compact set $K$ in the quotient space $X/M$, there exists a compact set $L\subset X$ such that $\pi(L)=K$, where $\pi: X\to X/M$ is the quotient map.

Is there any short proof for this? Since the quotient map has many nice properties.

Comment: I think this can be considered as a duplicate of the post you link to. This reformulation does not simplify the problem.

Comment: @AnneBauval Is there any way to uplift an old question so that it can get attention from people again?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.